# Attach to forked process on node using http

Tags: node.js, http

Exploring a project where I use [Node http server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener). I am perhaps trying to push quite a bit into this, but that's on me.

Basic concept:

Having a `main.js` script that:

1. Parses options (address, port, etc.)
2. [`fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options) a HTTP server script (which process GET / POST ++).
3. Initiate a CLI interface to control the server by using [`subprocess.send()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesssendmessage-sendhandle-options-callback) to the forked process (restart, stop, quit, dump-info, log requests etc.)

Now that is all good. I can start the server, control it etc. For intended use however, the server is started as a background process. If another request to start it is done a replay that it is running is posted and one use normal GET / POST request to communicate.

My question is if there is a way to attach to a running fork. Something like:

1. Server is started as a background process for Program A.
2. I open a shell and want to attach to the running server and use the `subprocess.send()` procedure. Partially because it is already implemented from the existing code, but mainly because it gives the option to send more verbose commands then `kill`, it seems cleaner as it is not part of the HTTP protocol: communicating with the process on a deeper level ...

It is perhaps not possible due to restrictions and I could rewrite for it to be all GET / POST based. (I.e. Start server and only use POST / GET / PUT etc.) – or there is a way to attach to the process and use `send()` as is.

In other words: I have a communication procedure that is for the end use (POST / GET) and other http usage; But also have a control interface that rely on direct process communication (process.send()).

On starting a CLI communication line I could ask any existing server to quit and then fork it, but that complicates things further.

Yet another way to describe it:

Having a HTTP server that accepts communication both by HTTP protocol and process messages. Is there a way to attach / send messages to an existing HTTP server process by a `subprocess.send()` like interface?